# Java LibGDX How to parse an JSON?

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx

I have a json file with content like this:

```
{
players: [
    {
        name: "",
        hp: 100
    },
    {
        name: "",
        hp: 120
    }
],
weapons: [
    {
        name: "Desert Eagle",
        price: 100
    },
    {
        name: "AK-47",
        price: 150
    }
]
}
```

How to parse it into an array of weapons? I already get content of this file as String. Then I use libgdx JsonReader:

```
JsonValue json = new JsonReader().parse(text);
```

Also I have a class for Weapons:

```
class Weapon {
    private String name;
    private int price;
}
```

What should I do next to put all the weapons into an array?

Comment: You can also use the GSON library to convert json->java and java->json easily: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no automatic mapping of parsed Json to Java object in libGDX, so you have to traverse Json and create appropriate objects by yourself. For sample that's how you parse `weapons`:

```
JsonValue json = new JsonReader().parse(text);
Array<Weapon> weapons = new Array<Weapon>();
JsonValue weaponsJson = json.get("weapons");
for (JsonValue weaponJson : weaponsJson.iterator()) // iterator() returns a list of children
{
    Weapon newWeapon = new Weapon();
    newWeapon.name = weaponJson.getString("name");
    newWeapon.price = weaponJson.getInt("price");
    weapons.add(newWeapon);
}
```