# Libgdx reading json array values

Tags: android, json, libgdx

I have a json response that I am trying to read values from unsuccessfully.
Below is the response

```
{ 
  "ID": 89, 
  "Ans": ["24", "12", "1", "18" ],
  "Que": "How Many hours are in a day?"
}
```

I can read values ID and Que successfully with the below code but not Ans array. Also how can i access individual values inside the Ans array? Thanks

```
JsonValue json = new JsonReader().parse(response);
String _id = json.getString("ID");
String que = json.getString("Que");

//not working
//String ans = json.getString("Ans");
//Json json1 = new Json();
//ArrayList<JsonValue> list = json1.fromJson(app.loadingScreen,ans);
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed by using

```
   String[] answers = ans.asStringArray();
   Gdx.app.log("App", "? : " + answers[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you achieve in this very manner?

```
ArrayList<String> ansList=new ArrayList();

JSONArray array= mainObject.optJSONArray("Ans");

for(int i=0; i <array.length();i++)
{

ansList.add(array.get(i));

}
```

Comment: There is no JSONArray in libgdx sadly...github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266823/java-libgdx-how-to-parse-an-json

Answer (score 0):

this should do:

```
JsonValue json = new JsonReader().parse(file);
JsonValue child = json.child;
int id = child.asInt());
child = child.next;
int[] ans = child.asIntArray();
child = child.next;
String que = child.asString();
```

Not elegant though, you can also try *JsonIterator*.

**UPD:**

```
JsonValue json = new JsonReader().parse(file);
JsonValue.JsonIterator it = json.iterator();
int id =  it.next().asInt();
int[] ans = it.next().asIntArray();
String que = it.next().asString();
```